# What is DMI Pool Data and why is it verified?

Tags: boot, bios, dmi

What is DMI Pool Data? Every time a computer here boots up it comes a message that says

> Verifying DMI Pool Data.............

And then it comes:

> AMD data changed...Update New Data to DMI!

What does that mean? Is there something wrong? Should I do something? Is this "Update New Data to DMI!" a comment about what it just did, or something I should do? It is a brand new Gigabyte motherboard with AMD 790X chipset and an AMD Phenom II processor. I have tried to look around and figure out what this is but can't figure it out. For example read something about that the battery was dead or something, but then it wouldn't remember the CMOS settings, would it? (which it does)

Never seen this before and it happens every single time the computer starts up. Just before the OS starts to launch. In addition the computer is quite unstable, but trying to run Windows 7 RC, so can't really be sure if it is the hardware, drivers or OS that is unstable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could also mean, that your mainboard is having some trouble reading from the hard drive. I had a similar problem when I had a USB stick attached and it wanted to boot/read from there first. Well and running a Microsoft Preview is always very likely to be unstable ;) 
I found some other hints on a [German forum entry](http://forum.biosflash.com/ftopic579.html) which may help you, too even though it is only when the bootup freezes at the DMI pool verifying:

1. Reset Bios settings
2. After hardware installation: Set "Force Update ESCD" or "Reset Configuration Data" to enabled
3. Broken IDE / SATA cable
4. Broken master boot record (MBR): Run fdisk /mbr and sys c: from a bootup terminal
5. Bad hardware, including BIOS chip
6. Virus

Comment: Seems to have been solved by installing Windows 7 RTM and updating the BIOS. Also I seem to have an external USB Drive that is causing some problems from time to time during booting...

Answer (score 6):

DMI stands for Desktop Management Interface. It is a way of storing information about your system. Its main use is for corporations to manage and track PCs they have purchased. Some OEMs also use DMI tables to store information used preactivate Windows installations. That is why you can reinstall the OS on a Dell or HP without getting the nag about activating within 60 days. DMI has been superseded by a newer standard called [CIM](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/cim/).

Beyond that its of no value to home users. As other's have mentioned, reseting the BIOS will usually make this message go away.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad board. I would update the BIOS, reset it to factory defaults, and if that doesn't do the trick, do an RMA on it and try a new one.

DMI stands for Desktop Management Interface and is the part of the BIOS that makes it easier for the operating system to get device information, etc. from the BIOS.

Comment: Aha. Cool. Will try that then :) Thanks a lot for replying even though someone tagged it as superuser material by the way!