# Acer AM1100 stuck on Verify DMI Pool Data

Tags: troubleshooting, bios, dmi

I have an Acer AM1100 and I just installed Windows 7 Ultimate. Windows has properly installed but right now, when I boot up the system, I get stuck on "Verify DMI Pool Data".

I also tried to reinstalled the whole thing but this happens again...

Any takers?

It's an Acer AM1100
Athlon x2
2go Ram
Sata HDD 320go

Comment: the DMI pool is fairly well-explained in this question (http://superuser.com/questions/13051/dmi-pool-data); in particular see Daff's answer which provides some troubleshooting tips that may help you (http://superuser.com/questions/13051/dmi-pool-data/15630#15630).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After like 10h of work on trying to install Windows 7 on that sh(*&"!)&! computer. It's just not compatible. Vista Ultimate is...

Thanks.